# Sparse plus dense matrix operation using cuSPARSE

Tags: matrix, cuda

Is it possible to add a sparse matrix and a dense matrix using `cuSPARSE`? In `cuBLAS`, I'd just treat the matrices as vectors and use `axpy`. `cuSPARSE` does have `axpy` for sparse/dense vectors, but it cannot be used for matrices because sparse vectors and matrices have different memory structure.

Comment: Would the result need to be dense or sparse?

Comment: The result should be dense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cusparse has dense-to-sparse and sparse-to-dense [conversion routines](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#cusparse-format-conversion-reference). You could:

1. convert the sparse matrix to dense (e.g. with [`cusparse<t>csr2dense`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#cusparse-lt-t-gt-csr2dense)), then add the two with [`cublas<t>geam`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-geam), producing a dense matrix result
2. convert the dense matrix to sparse (e.g. with [`cusparse<t>dense2csr`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#cusparse-lt-t-gt-dense2csr)), then use [`cusparse<t>csrgeam`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#cusparse-lt-t-gt-csrgeam) to produce a sparse result

Note that using `cusparse<t>geam` is a little bit more involved than just a single function call, but the usage methodology is given in [the documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#cusparse-lt-t-gt-csrgeam).  Also, when using `cusparse<t>dense2csr`, you will likely want to use `cusparse<t>nnz` to help with the storage allocations needed.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question.  I ended up writing my own kernel to avoid extra memory and computation.  I think they really should provide axpy (and other level 1 routines) for matrices in the library as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fully worked example with a customized kernel summing up a sparse matrix `A` stored in CSR format with a dense matrix `B` providing a dense matrix `C`. The customized kernel explicitly deals with the mapping between the CSR and dense indices.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <cusparse.h>

#define     BLOCKSIZEX  16
#define     BLOCKSIZEY  16

/*******************/
/* iDivUp FUNCTION */
/*******************/
int iDivUp(int a, int b){ return ((a % b) != 0) ? (a / b + 1) : (a / b); }

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
// --- Credit to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api
void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort = true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) { exit(code); }
    }
}

void gpuErrchk(cudaError_t ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }

/***************************/
/* CUSPARSE ERROR CHECKING */
/***************************/
static const char *_cusparseGetErrorEnum(cusparseStatus_t error)
{
    switch (error)
    {

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_MATRIX_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_MATRIX_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_ZERO_PIVOT:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_ZERO_PIVOT";
    }

    return "<unknown>";
}

inline void __cusparseSafeCall(cusparseStatus_t err, const char *file, const int line)
{
    if (CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "CUSPARSE error in file '%s', line %d, error %s\nterminating!\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, \
            _cusparseGetErrorEnum(err)); \
            assert(0); \
    }
}

extern "C" void cusparseSafeCall(cusparseStatus_t err) { __cusparseSafeCall(err, __FILE__, __LINE__); }

/*****************************/
/* SETUP DESCRIPTOR FUNCTION */
/*****************************/
void setUpDescriptor(cusparseMatDescr_t &descrA, cusparseMatrixType_t matrixType, cusparseIndexBase_t indexBase) {
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrA));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatType(descrA, matrixType));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descrA, indexBase));
}

/********************************************************/
/* DENSE TO SPARSE CONVERSION FOR REAL DOUBLE PRECISION */
/********************************************************/
void dense2SparseD(const double * __restrict__ d_A_dense, int **d_nnzPerVector, double **d_A,
    int **d_A_RowIndices, int **d_A_ColIndices, int &nnz, cusparseMatDescr_t descrA,
    const cusparseHandle_t handle, const int M, const int N) {

    const int lda = M;                      // --- Leading dimension of dense matrix

    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_nnzPerVector[0], M * sizeof(int)));

    // --- Compute the number of nonzero elements per row and the total number of nonzero elements 
    //     the dense d_A_dense
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDnnz(handle, CUSPARSE_DIRECTION_ROW, M, N, descrA, d_A_dense,
        lda, d_nnzPerVector[0], &nnz));

    // --- Device side sparse matrix
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A[0], nnz * sizeof(double)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A_RowIndices[0], (M + 1) * sizeof(int)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A_ColIndices[0], nnz * sizeof(int)));

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDdense2csr(handle, M, N, descrA, d_A_dense, lda, d_nnzPerVector[0],
        d_A[0], d_A_RowIndices[0], d_A_ColIndices[0]));
}

/********************************/
/* SPARSE + DENSE CUSTOM KERNEL */
/********************************/
__global__ void sparsePlusDense(const double * __restrict__ d_A, const int * __restrict__ d_A_RowIndices,
                                const int * __restrict__ d_A_ColIndices, const double * __restrict__ d_B, 
                                double * __restrict__ d_C, const int M, const int N) {

    const int tidx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    const int tidy = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;

    if ((tidx >= N) || (tidy >= M)) return;

    const int   row         = tidy;
    const int   nnzRow      = d_A_RowIndices[tidy + 1] - d_A_RowIndices[tidy];
    if (tidx >= nnzRow) return;

    const int   col         = d_A_ColIndices[d_A_RowIndices[tidy] + tidx];

    d_C[row * N + col] = d_C[row * N + col] + d_A[d_A_RowIndices[tidy] + tidx];
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    cusparseHandle_t    handle;

    // --- Initialize cuSPARSE
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreate(&handle));

    // --- Initialize matrix descriptors
    cusparseMatDescr_t descrA;
    setUpDescriptor(descrA, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO);

    /**************************/
    /* SETTING UP THE PROBLEM */
    /**************************/
    const int M = 5;                        // --- Number of rows
    const int N = 4;                        // --- Number of columns

    // --- Host side dense matrix
    double *h_A_dense = (double*)malloc(M * N * sizeof(*h_A_dense));

    // --- Column-major storage
    h_A_dense[0] = 0.4612;  h_A_dense[5] = 0.0;       h_A_dense[10] = 1.3;     h_A_dense[15] = 0.0;
    h_A_dense[1] = 0.0;     h_A_dense[6] = 1.443;     h_A_dense[11] = 0.0;     h_A_dense[16] = 0.0;
    h_A_dense[2] = -0.0006; h_A_dense[7] = 0.4640;    h_A_dense[12] = 0.0723;  h_A_dense[17] = 0.0;
    h_A_dense[3] = 0.3566;  h_A_dense[8] = 0.0;       h_A_dense[13] = 0.7543;  h_A_dense[18] = 0.0;
    h_A_dense[4] = 0.;      h_A_dense[9] = 0.0;       h_A_dense[14] = 0.0;     h_A_dense[19] = 0.1;

    // --- Create device array and copy host array to it
    double *d_A_dense;  gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A_dense, M * N * sizeof(double)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_A_dense, h_A_dense, M * N * sizeof(*d_A_dense), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    /*******************************/
    /* FROM DENSE TO SPARSE MATRIX */
    /*******************************/
    int nnz = 0;            // --- Number of nonzero elements in dense matrix
    int *d_nnzPerVector;    // --- Device side number of nonzero elements per row

    double *d_A;        // --- Sparse matrix values - array of size nnz
    int *d_A_RowIndices;    // --- "Row indices"
    int *d_A_ColIndices;    // --- "Column indices"

    dense2SparseD(d_A_dense, &d_nnzPerVector, &d_A, &d_A_RowIndices, &d_A_ColIndices, nnz, descrA,
        handle, M, N);

    /*************************/
    /* DENSE MATRIX OPERANDS */
    /*************************/
    // --- Host side dense matrix
    double *h_B_dense = (double*)malloc(M * N * sizeof(*h_B_dense));

    // --- Column-major storage
    h_B_dense[0] = 1.5;     h_B_dense[5] = -0.2;    h_B_dense[10] = -0.9;       h_B_dense[15] = 1.1;
    h_B_dense[1] = 2.1;     h_B_dense[6] = 2.0;     h_B_dense[11] = 1.1;        h_B_dense[16] = -0.009;
    h_B_dense[2] = -2;      h_B_dense[7] = -0.82;   h_B_dense[12] = 1.2;        h_B_dense[17] = 1.21;
    h_B_dense[3] = -0.001;  h_B_dense[8] = -1.1;    h_B_dense[13] = 0.887;      h_B_dense[18] = 1.1143;
    h_B_dense[4] = 1.1;     h_B_dense[9] = 2.1;     h_B_dense[14] = -1.1213;    h_B_dense[19] = 5.4334;

    // --- Create device array and copy host array to it
    double *d_B_dense;  gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_B_dense, M * N * sizeof(double)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_B_dense, h_B_dense, M * N * sizeof(*d_B_dense), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // --- Allocate space for the result e initialize it
    double *d_C_dense;  gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_C_dense, M * N * sizeof(double)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_C_dense, d_B_dense, M * N * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice));

    /*********************************/
    /* RUN THE SPARSE-DENSE ADDITION */
    /*********************************/
    dim3 GridDim(iDivUp(N, BLOCKSIZEX), iDivUp(M, BLOCKSIZEY));
    dim3 BlockDim(BLOCKSIZEX, BLOCKSIZEY);
    sparsePlusDense << <GridDim , BlockDim>> >(d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, d_B_dense, d_C_dense, M, N);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    /*******************************************************/
    /* CHECKING THE RESULTS FOR SPARSE TO DENSE CONVERSION */
    /*******************************************************/
    double *h_C_dense = (double *)malloc(M * N * sizeof(double));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_C_dense, d_C_dense, M * N * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    printf("\nFirst dense operand matrix (column-major storage) \n");
    for (int m = 0; m < M; m++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
            printf("%f\t", h_A_dense[n * M + m]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\nSecond dense operand matrix (row-major storage) \n");
    for (int m = 0; m < M; m++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
            printf("%f\t", h_B_dense[n + m * N]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\nReference dense matrix (the first has column-major storage, the second row-major\n");
    for (int m = 0; m < M; m++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
            printf("%f\t", h_A_dense[n * M + m] + h_B_dense[n + m * N]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\nSecond dense operand matrix (row-major storage) \n");
    for (int m = 0; m < M; m++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
            printf("%f\t", h_C_dense[n + m * N]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```